# How to find y when x is given and a list of points?

Tags: java, structure

There's a group:

```
S = {(xi,yi)|1 ≤ i ≤ n}
```

of n points. There are no 2 points `(xi,yi) (xj,yj) where xi = xj and yi = yj`.
It means the x and y values are unique. I need to find a data structure that supports the functions:

1. Given x, return the value of y where (x,y) is in S. If it doesn't exist return "not exist".
2. Given y, return the value x where (x,y) is in S. If it doesn't exist return "not exist".

A simple solution will be to create two sorted arrays (one sorted according to the x values and the second sorted according to the y values). To find y with a given x will take `O(logn)`, by using binary search. The same for finding x.

**I can't use more than one array (of n elements) and each element is a point**.
I need to find an efficient data structure that can do those actions in an optimal time. I need to find:

`T(first function)+T(second action)`.

**Which data structure is the most efficient in this case?**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you just need a pair of maps:

```
Map<TypeOfX, TypeOfY> mapXtoY;
Map<TypeOfY, TypeOfX> mapYtoX;
```

You can use any concrete implementation of `Map`, e.g. `HashMap`, `TreeMap`, `LinkedHashMap`...

To add a point, you simply add it to both:

```
void addPoint(TypeOfX x, TypeOfY y) {
  mapXtoY.put(x, y);
  mapYtoX.put(y, x);
}
```

And you can get the `y` for an `x` by using:

```
TypeOfY y = mapXtoY.get(x);
```

and vice versa.

Libraries such as Guava provide [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) implementations, which maintain this two-directional mapping for you.

Comment: only there can be multiple values of x for a a certain y and vice versa. example: (1, 1) (1, 3), you would have two entries in the `mapYtoX` and only one in `mapXtoY`.

Comment: The use of the definite article in the question (e.g. "Given y, return **the** value of x") precludes that case.

Comment: Thank you. What is the complexity of it? and what does the map do in general?

Comment: Depends upon the choice of `Map`. Consult the specific javadoc to see the guarantees on the complexities of their respective operations. And in general, a map maps from keys to values.

Comment: "Which data structure is the most efficient?" is the question you asked. If you can only use an array, then clearly the most efficient data structure you can use is an array.

Comment: But you don't need an array of data points in addition if you use this approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108151/discussion-between-rotemhas-and-andy-turner).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I dont read your condition '(xi, yi), (xj, yj) => xi != xj && yi != yj' as you do, to me this only means that the coordinates are unique (not each x and each y).

So you first must create a Point object

```
public class Point {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
}
```

Then store all your points into a unique array (you said you need it)

```
Point[] POINTS = ... // fill your array depending on your input
```

Finally wrap ths array into a class that provides the methods you need

```
public class PointCollection {
    public Point[] points;
    public Map<Integer, List<Integer>> mapX = new HashMap<Integer; List<Integer>>();
    public Map<Integer, List<Integer>> mapY = new HashMap<Integer; List<Integer>>();
    public PointCollection(Points[] points) { 
        this.points = points;
        for (Point p : points) {
            mapX.getOrDefault(p.x, new ArrayList<Integer>()).add(p.y);
            mapY.getOrDefault(p.y, new ArrayList<Integer>()).add(p.x);
        }    
    }

    public int[] getMatchingY(int x) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (Point p : this.points)) {
            if (p.x == x) result.add(p.y);
        }
        return result.toArray(new int[result.size()]);
    }

    public int[] getMatchingX(int y) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (Point p : this.points)) {
            if (p.y == y) result.add(p.x);
        }
        return result.toArray(new int[result.size()]);
    }

    public int[] getMatchingYFromMap(int x) {
        List<Integer> result = mapX.getOrDefault(x, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        return result.toArray(new int[result.size()]);
    }

    public int[] getMatchingXFromMap(int y) {
        List<Integer> result = mapY.getOrDefault(y, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        return result.toArray(new int[result.size()]);
    }
}
```

edit: added solution based on map

Comment: Is it O(n) complexity?

Comment: yes, note that it would be hard to go to a higher complexity for this problem ^^

Comment: Thank you but I thought about this solution. I think they want me to find a better one, though this solution does find x and y.

Comment: Oh. I asked and I don't have to use an array, I just can't use more than one

Comment: Since you said you need to use ONLY one array, this is gonna be hard :p Otherwise you can build 2 maps as suggested by Andy Tumer, this will increase the initialization cost (to o(n)) but then the method calls fall to o(1)

Comment: OK thank you very much. Which map should I use and how does the map work?